# Mabox Android - not getting location updates

Tags: android, geolocation, location, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using the Mapbox SDK and I want to move and zoom the map to the current location.  If I enable the location layer, I get the dot in the correct spot.  However my location engine listener isn't being called so I can't move the camera.

In `onCreateView` I start a connection with a `GoogleApiClient`.  Once that's connected I use it to check the location settings to see if they're turned on (after checking for permission for location).  If that succeeds, I do this:

```
if (locationEngine == null) {
   locationEngine = new LocationSource(getActivity());
   locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
}
Location location = locationEngine.getLastLocation(); // This returns null

onLocationChanged(location); // This moves the camera if a location is passed in

locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(locationEngineListener);

// This works, the location layer functions properly    
getMap(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

                mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Here's what `locationEngineListener` does:

```
private class Listener implements LocationEngineListener {
        @Override
        public void onConnected() {
            // No action needed here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            CurrentLocationMap.this.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
    }
```

The problem is `onLocationChanged` is never called.

Answer (score 2):

This is the exactly working solution, probaly in slight different circumstances. But I wanted to add some little explanation steps so that anybody gets the exact concepts. I don't see what LocationEngine you are using in your code. Here I am using LocationServices.FusedLocationApi as my LocationEngine.

1) onCreate() of Android Component (Eg, **Activity**, **Fragment** or **Service**. *Note: Not IntentService*), **build** and then **connect** the GoogleApiClient as below.

```
buildGoogleApiClient();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

where, buildGoogleApiClient() implementation is,

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

    }
```

Later on onDestroy(), you can disconnect GoogleApiClient as,

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service destroyed!");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

**The step 1 makes sure you build and connect the GoogleApiClient.**

1) GoogleApiClient instance first time gets connected on method onConnected(). Now, your next step should look onConnected() method.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected!");
        buildLocationSettingsRequest();
        createLocationRequest();
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(TAG, " Location: " + location); //may return **null** because, I can't guarantee location has been changed immmediately 
    }
```

Above, you called a method **createLocationRequest()** to create location request. The method **createLocationRequest()** looks like below.

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
        //remove location updates so that it resets
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this); //Import should not be **android.Location.LocationListener**
    //import should be **import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener**;

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        //restart location updates with the new interval
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }
```

3) Now, on onLocationChange() callback of LocationListener interface, you get new location.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location Changed!");
        Log.i(TAG, " Location: " + location); //I guarantee,I get the changed location here

    }
```

**You get the result like this in Logcat:**
03-22 18:34:17.336 817-817/com.LiveEarthquakesAlerts I/LocationTracker:  Location: Location[fused 37.421998,-122.084000 acc=20 et=+15m35s840ms alt=0.0]

To be able to do these three steps, you should have configured your build.gradle as below:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do that as a fallback position but the Mapbox API (which it's what I'm using) seems much simpler so if I can get that working I'd like to. However that is a great answer for the Google API.

Comment: The code snippet I provided here is exact code that I used for one of my apps in Google Play Store. It is 100% working code. The idea is the same. 
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.LiveEarthquakesAlerts

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, it's just using a different API than the one I'm using.